# Insert svg image in latex as figure: excessive spacing around it

Tags: spacing, floats, svg

Good afternoon, I have a problem related to insert `.svg` images in latex as a figure.
I have tried to insert an image but it leaves too much spacing before the image, and it is not centered either. I have tried the following procedure:

```
    \begin{figure}[htbp]
        \centering
        \includesvg[width=1.25\textwidth]{figures/modelo_1d_sinruido.svg}
        \caption{Simulated wave captured by a sensor located at a distance from the force that produces the wave. It has been simulated with the 1-dimensional wave model in polar coordinates with Matlab.}
        \label{fig:modelo1}
    \end{figure}
```

Do you know why it doesn't centre it despite indicating it and leaves so much space in front of the image? Thank you very much.

[image: In this image you can see in yellow the excess of space in front of the image and that it is not centered.]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE Check, how much white space has image y inserting image in `fbox`. It should be tied to image, if not, than you need to remove white space by some program or using `trim` and `clip` options defined in the `graphicx` package.

Comment: Thank you very much!